# Passing Data From View To Controller Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form defined as follow.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("PRoll", "Payroll", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmPRoll" })){%>

    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.keyid, new { @class = "required", Style = "width:190px", @maxlength = "15" })%>
    ....
<% } %>
```

and the controller as

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var bo = new PayrollInfo();
    return View(bo);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetailPage(string keyid)
{
    //TempData["prid"] = p_payrollid;
    return RedirectToAction("PayDtl/" + keyid, "Payroll", keyid);
}
```

I submit the form through jquery as follow

```
function DetailPage() {
    var rol = $('#keyid').val();
    $('#frmPRoll').attr('action', '/Proll/DetailPage/'+rol).submit();
}
```

The keyid value in controllers DetailPage action method is allways null. It never gets populated with actual data from view.

How do i get the keyid value from the view in the controller ?

thanks

Comment: When debugging your `DetailPage`, what is contents of `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` collections?

Answer (score 2):

```
function DetailPage() {
    // TODO: don't hardcode /Proll/DetailPage here: use url helpers
    $('#frmPRoll').attr('action', '/Proll/DetailPage').submit();
}
```

Since there's already a textbox within this form containing the keyid value, when you submit the form to the `DetailPage` action, this value will be POSTed as the `keyid` action parameter.

Also you are using a wrong overload of the `RedirectToAction` method. It should be like this, assuming of course that your PayDtl expects an argument called `keyid`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetailPage(string keyid)
{
    return RedirectToAction("PayDtl", "Payroll", new { keyid = keyid });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function DetailPage() {
    var rol = $('#keyid').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("DetailPage", "Proll")',
            data: "keyid=" + rol
            success: function (result) {
            ...
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but i need to do full post/ submit as i am trying to redirect to a different controller/action